# Question about shipper carrier codes for orders

Tags: magento2, shipping, rest-api

I am writing integration code to connect Magento to our ERP system. I need to pass the shipping carrier code to our ERP order creation but the code in the order does not match our internal carrier code.

I want to change the Magento carrier codes to align with our ERP codes to avoid having to do a lookup to convert the codes back and forth. I can't figure out where these codes are stored on the Magneto side, and I can't find any documentation explaining how to manage these codes.

Example: (From Magento order)

"shipping_description": "UPS - UPS Next Day Air®",
...

```
 "shipping": {
   "address": {
     "address_type": "shipping",
     "city": "nowheresville",
     "company": "foo",
     "country_id": "US",
     "customer_address_id": 84,
     "email": "RandomGuy@fu-co.com",
     "entity_id": 305,
     "firstname": "Random",
     "lastname": "Dude",
     "parent_id": 187,
     "postcode": "17602",
     "region": "Pennsylvania",
     "region_code": "PA",
     "region_id": 51,
     "street": [
        "1313 mockingbird lane"
      ],
      "telephone": "555-1212"
      },
      **"method": "ups_01",**
```

Here the method is set to ups_01

My hope was that I could change the string "ups_01" to match our existing codes.

Can anyone provide some guidance on how/if this can be configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got some bad news. Codes are often hardcoded in code

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/OfflineShipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php#L25

But also there are refences in XML

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Analytics/etc/di.xml#L144-L145

Not a great example but demonstrates my point.

Therefore it would be far less painless to just work with what you've got and then convert back and forth.

Comment: I was hoping this was not the case but I am not surprised.